# Backend and frontend work seperately fine. but why frontend not load backend data on vercel?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, vercel

I deployed my frontend and backend in vercel today. before this happen there was a error not 404 in backend. but when someone in stackoverflow said that change root file server.js--> index.js. so i do that and backend now work fine. not both frontend and backend deployed and work fine but backend data not load to frontend.

this is my backend after deployed

[image]

this is the error come from frontend

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

[image]

//backend index.js

```js
//import required modules
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors')

const NoteRoutes = require('./routes/noteRoutes')


const { getCategory, deleteCategory, getOneCategryData } = require('./controller/categoryController')
const { getDynamicNoteData, DeleteInActiveNotes, AutoHardDeleteNotes } = require('./controller/noteController')

//initialize express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse incoming requests with JSON
app.use(express.json())

//middleware to handle cors policy 
app.use(cors());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to Note API' })
})

app.use('/note', NoteRoutes)


//manually create routes because of casting issues
app.get('/search', getDynamicNoteData)
app.delete('/remove', DeleteInActiveNotes)
app.get('/category', getCategory)
app.get('/category/:id', getOneCategryData)
app.delete('/category/:id', deleteCategory)


const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const URL = process.env.URL;


//establish connection to mongodb  database using mongoose
mongoose.connect(URL)
    //if connection success display the success messages
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected with MongoDB");

        //call auto deletion function
        AutoHardDeleteNotes()

        //app listning port
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log("Server is running on port " + PORT);
        })
    })
    //if there is a error on connecting show display the error message
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Application has Following Errors:  \n" + err);
    })
```

//some code on frontend

```js
const fetchDefaultNotes=()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/note/active')
    .then((res)=>{
      setNotes(res.data.data);
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch((err)=>
    console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

when you run locally your frontend and backend, i work fine and all process done right.. even when i run my backend code, deployed frontend work without any error..

Comment: do you install cors correctly??

Comment: yes. i install cors correctly